# check if an javascript array contains all of the values of another array

Tags: javascript

### How to find if stringB contains all of the values of stringA?

Imagining you want to make a new string (`stringB`) out of `stringA`, when you take a value from stringA, it'll disappear from stringA, you can't use it twice.

So if `stringB` has repeated values, but `stringA` only has one of that value, then the  program should return `false`.

Example Input:

```
stringA = "A B C D"

stringB = "B B C D"
```

Example Output:

```
false
```

Because `stringA` only has one "B".

Example Input:

```
stringA = "apple banana orange mango"

stringB = "banana orange"
```

Example Output:

`true`

Here is what I have, but it return `true` when it should've returned `false` can anyone tell me what is wrong with my logic or what should the solution be? Thanks!

```js
let arrayContainsArray = (a, b) => {
  let a_array = a.split(" ")
  let b_array = b.split(" ")

  for(let i = 0; i < b_array.length; i++) {
    if (a_array.includes(b_array[i])) {
      let index = a_array.indexOf(b_array[i])
      a_array.splice(index, 1)
    } else {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}

console.log(arrayContainsArray('two times three is not four', 'two times two is four'));
```

Comment: Your title doesn't quite match with your question. A string is not an array. What's the point of having an array with a single value? Or are `stringA` and `stringB` actually strings and not arrays?

Comment: What should be the output for `arrayContainsArray('B C D', 'B B C D')`? `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work, because it always returns anything (if not false, then true) in first iteration (reason: return true statement is in for loop). Try this:

```js
let arrayContainsArray = (a, b) => {
  let a_array = a.split(" ")
  let b_array = b.split(" ")

  for (let i = 0; i < b_array.length; i++) {
    if (a_array.includes(b_array[i])) {
      let index = a_array.indexOf(b_array[i])
      a_array.splice(index, 1)
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

console.log(arrayContainsArray('two times three is not four', 'two times two is four'));
console.log(arrayContainsArray('A B C D', 'B B C D'));
console.log(arrayContainsArray('apple banana orange mango', 'banana orange'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `every` to loop thru the array and check the condition and `includes` to check if an array contains a certain element.

```js
let arrayContainsArray = (a, b) => {
  let a_array = a.split(" ")
  let b_array = b.split(" ")

  return a_array.every(o => b_array.includes(o));
}

console.log(arrayContainsArray('two times three is not four', 'two times two is four'));
console.log(arrayContainsArray('two times two is four', 'two times two is four'));
```

---

Another option is to make the `b_array` into a `new Set`. Use `has` to check if a set includes a certain element.

```js
let arrayContainsArray = (a, b) => {
  let a_array = a.split(" ")
  let b_array = b.split(" ")

  let set = new Set(b_array);
  return a_array.every(o => set.has(o));
}

console.log(arrayContainsArray('two times three is not four', 'two times two is four'));
console.log(arrayContainsArray('two times two is four', 'two times two is four'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my approach using jquery each and inArray.

```
// created function
function existAll(baseArray, arrayToCompare) {
var result = true;       

$.each(baseArray, function (ix, data) {
    if (!($.inArray(data, arrayToCompare) !== -1)) {
        result = false;
        return false;
    }
});

return result;
```

}

```
// usage
alert(existAll([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5,4]));
```